# wi-fi fails for a few days then starts working again

Tags: wi-fi

Several times over the past year the wi-fi failed then, after about 5 day, it started working again.

How to diagnose the problem?

- resetting the phone's software restores the wi-fi connection
- wi-fi icon says it is connected but it is unable to connect to the internet.
- Connecting to the router IP address times out. All attempts to connect to the internet via wifi time out, as far as I can tell.
- connecting to the wi-fi with other devices works fine
- wi-fi routers are visible
- Android version 4.2.2

Ideas?

Comment: for a start to diagnose the issue pull the logs and if more info is needed  the kernel logs (dmesg) too.